# Flex Mate - send object with id property to the server

Tags: apache-flex, amf, mate

Is there any way to create an Object using the ObjectBuilder with an id property that is bound to another value?

The following does not work since "id" is reserved:

```
<ObjectBuilder generator="{Object}" cache="none">
    <Properties id="{event.list}" />
</ObjectBuilder>
```

The following does not work either since event.list should be bound:

```
<RemoteObjectInvoker instance="{jobService}" method="DeleteJob"
    arguments="{{id:event.list}}">
```

Is there any other way to send an "id" to a server API?

Just to clarify: this code is inside an EventHandler in the mapping file:

```
<EventHandlers type="{JobEvent.DELETE}">
    <ObjectBuilder .../>
    <RemoteObjectInvoker instance="{jobService}" method="DeleteJob" arguments="{{id:event.list}}">
        <resultHandlers>
        ...
        </resultHandlers>
    </RemoteObjectInvoker>
</EventHandlers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the first ObjectBuilder, is this invoked upon pre-initialize or what's the event to which you're referring for the id?

On the RemoteObjectInvoker, is this part of a series of handlers in the map or what fires the event that the map should capture?

Answer (score 0):

My memory is that the arguments parameter is looking for an array. Have you tried

arguments="{[argument1]}"

Back when I used Mate more, I would be using a custom event (which you are) with an id parameter. From the way it's written, I assume that the list parameter of the event is actually the id, correct?

Comment: Hi John, the arguments parameter can get either an array or a scalar (passed as the first argument to the method).
the list parameter is an array of id's, yes ...

Comment: Frustrating, I'm sure. I'll  play a little myself this afternoon. Out of curiosity, is the RemoteObject PHP, Colfusion CFC, or what? Is it getting the primary call and id is simply null when  it hits?

Comment: The server is in transition from PHP to Python. In both, the id is received as the following object '{u'source': u'event', u'sourceKey': u'list'}'